# Angular Library paths alias declared in tsconfig.json not working: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve

Tags: angular, typescript, path, libraries, tsconfig

I'am developing an Angular (v12) library and a small app to test it that have the following structure:

```
├── projects
│   ├── my-app
│   │   ├── karma.conf.js
│   │   ├── src
│   │   ├── tsconfig.app.json
│   │   └── tsconfig.spec.json
│   └── my-lib
│       ├── README.md
│       ├── karma.conf.js
│       ├── ng-package.json
│       ├── node_modules
│       ├── package-lock.json
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── src
│       ├── tsconfig.lib.json
│       ├── tsconfig.lib.prod.json
│       └── tsconfig.spec.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

In the root ./tsconfig.json I declare paths aliases (as I understand to be recognized by VS Code):

```
 {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "paths": {
      "my-lib": [
        "dist/my-lib/my-lib",
        "dist/my-lib"
      ],
      "@services/*": [
        "projects/my-lib/src/lib/services/*"
      ]
    },
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

In the ./projects/my-lib/tsconfig.lib.json I declare again the paths aliases (as I understand to be interpreted by the ng-packagr compiler):

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
      "paths": {
        "@services/*": [ "src/lib/services/*" ],
      },
      "sourceMap": true,
      "declaration": false,
      "module": "es2015",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "target": "es5",
      "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
      ],
      "lib": [
        "es2017",
        "dom"
      ]
    }
  }
```

The ./angular.json is referencing the tsconfig.lib.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-lib": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "projects/my-lib",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/my-lib/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr",
          "options": {
            "project": "projects/my-lib/ng-package.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/my-lib/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
            },
            "development": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/my-lib/tsconfig.lib.json"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
```

The Library is compiling without any errors.

When I import the library in my-app and I want to import a service for example, It does not resolve the paths aliases :

```
./node_modules/my-lib/fesm2015/my-lib.mjs:11:0-56 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@services/my-lib/my-lib.service' in '/Users/***/projects/ANGULAR/angular-tour-of-heroes/node_modules/my-lib/fesm2015'
    
    Error: node_modules/my-lib/lib/custom-page/custom-page.component.d.ts:2:30 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@services/my-lib/my-lib.service' or its corresponding type declarations.
    
    2 import { MyLibService } from '@services/my-lib/my-lib.service';

Error: node_modules/my-lib/lib/custom-page/custom-page.component.d.ts:2:30 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@services/my-lib/my-lib.service' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import { MyLibService } from '@services/my-lib/my-lib.service';
```

I tried any combinations of configuration in the world, paths seems to be impossible to be used in an Angular Library

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. 
Did you able to get this resolved?

Comment: Same issue here @Tom Apparently it's not supported at all for libraries: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35499#issuecomment-587395899

Answer (score 0):

The tsconfig file for production is `projects/my-lib/tsconfig.lib.prod.json` (as declared in angular.json), so you probably have forgotten to set the alias path for production. To my understanding, this should point to the right path in the `dist` folder.

That said, I have the same issue (but already when running dev locally), so this is just a guess.

### Edit:

I got it working locally, and am now facing a similar issue when trying to build. In my case it's an error `not an absolute path` (no ref to where that error comes from), and when I use the alias everywhere in my components, a lot of `No suitable injection token for parameter 'tooltip' of class 'MyComponent'.` errors.

I still hope you can make it work, but perhaps my answer won't lead to the solution.